# How to get Address from Lat Long

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, location

Hello i am creating App for iOS and Android. The issue i want to fix that on the load on page i want to display the map with the address. I can get Lat Long successfully but i cannot getting address that i want to display on a label. Below is my code that i am using.

```
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

  private Position _position;
    // Map map;
    double Lat, Long;
    string address = "";

   public TestPage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();

        GetPosition();
        if (_position != null)
        {
            Lat = _position.Latitude;
            Long = _position.Longitude;
        }
        //Task<String> str = GetAddress();
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(Lat, Long), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
        var position = new Position(Lat, Long);
        var pin = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = position,
            Label = ""                
        };
        map.Pins.Add(pin);
        var zoomLevel = 17.83;
        var latlongdegrees = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));

        map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(position, latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));

        LabelTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string recentAddress = address;  // trying to get adderss for location 
    }
```

**GetPosition()**

```
public async void GetPosition()
    {
        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position = null;
        try
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100.0;

            position = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

            if (position != null)
            {
                _position = new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                //got a cahched position, so let's use it.
                return;
            }

            if (!locator.IsGeolocationAvailable || !locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
            {
                //not available or enabled
                return;
            }

            position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null, true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error(ex.Message, Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException), ex.Source, ex.StackTrace);
        }
        _position = new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
        if (position == null)
            return;

    }
```

**GetAddress()**

```
 public async Task<String> GetAddress()
        {
           // string Addrsss = "";
            try
            {
                Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder();

                if (_position != null)
                {
                    var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(_position);
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    foreach (var a in possibleAddresses)
                    {
                        address += a + "\n";
                    }
                }
                return address;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I also try to get the current address on `OnAppearing()`

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        this.Appearing += TestPage_Appearing; //Subscribe to event
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    protected async void TestPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
         GetPosition();
        address= await GetAddress();
        string a = address;
        this.Appearing -= TestPage_Appearing; //Unsubscribe 
    }
```

Comment: GetPosition is async and should be called using await

Comment: @Jason i am getting the position, but i want to get the Address from the Position that is not working.

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  Does it give you an error or exception?  Does it hang?  Does it crash?  What exactly is it doing?

Comment: @Jason not any exception or error i am getting before the` OnAppearing()` method start map loaded on the screen and address is not displaying

Comment: have you used the debugger to verify that you are not getting any results?  It's not clear from the code you posted how you are calling GetAddress or what you are doing with the results.

Comment: Ok, also getted the position data,yes?However, not get adress and show in `OnAppearing()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get placemark address using Xamarin.Essentials as below,

```
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        await GetAddress();
    }

    private async Task GetAddress()
    {
        var lat = 47.673988;
        var lon = -122.121513;

        var placemarks = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(lat, lon);

        var placemark = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();
        if (placemark != null)
        {
            var geocodeAddress =
                $"AdminArea:       {placemark.AdminArea}\n" +
                $"CountryCode:     {placemark.CountryCode}\n" +
                $"CountryName:     {placemark.CountryName}\n" +
                $"FeatureName:     {placemark.FeatureName}\n" +
                $"Locality:        {placemark.Locality}\n" +
                $"PostalCode:      {placemark.PostalCode}\n" +
                $"SubAdminArea:    {placemark.SubAdminArea}\n" +
                $"SubLocality:     {placemark.SubLocality}\n" +
                $"SubThoroughfare: {placemark.SubThoroughfare}\n" +
                $"Thoroughfare:    {placemark.Thoroughfare}\n";

            Console.WriteLine(geocodeAddress);
        }
    }
```

refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?tabs=android) for in depth details
Also [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-geocoding-get-full-addressplacemark-using-xamarin-essentials/) for detailed implementation

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to get the address when page open is this possible i can get the address when page open.

Comment: OnAppearing i try several time but noting i am getting value. You can view my above code part `TestPage_Appearing` and advice me. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the above code. It's working. I've tested.